# Force different layouts for WooCommerce pages on Genesis Framework

Tags: wordpress, function, layout, woocommerce, force-layout

I am trying to achieve different layouts for WooCommerce pages. I'm running WordPress4.9.7, Genesis Framework 2.6.1, and WooCommerce 3.4.3. Theme settings layout is set to content-sidebar. I want the Cart, Checkout, My Account, and Single Product pages to have a full width layout, and I want the Shop, and Product Category (parent categories) to have a sidebar-content layout. This is the code I have come up with, and while it does force full width on the Cart, Checkout, etc pages, it does not force the sidebar-content layout for the Shop and Product Category pages.

```
//* Force layouts on WooCommerce pages
add_filter( 'genesis_site_layout', 'sweetpea_woo_layouts' );
function sweetpea_woo_layouts() {
if( is_page ( array( 'shop' )) || 'product-category' == get_post_type() ) {
return 'sidebar-content';
 }
if ( is_page( array( 'cart', 'checkout', 'my-account' )) || 'product' == get_post_type() ) {
 return 'full-width-content';
 }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how to make this work to achieve the different layouts for WooCommerce? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Force full content layout on product category, product tag archives and all single products**

write this code in function.php file--

```html
add_action( 'get_header', 'sk_force_layout' );
function sk_force_layout() {

 if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) || is_tax( 'product_tag' ) || is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
  add_filter( 'genesis_pre_get_option_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );
 }

}
```

Hope.... it's work!!